# Laravel - Open/download files on browser from existing server

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a project in laravel that list files and when i click in each file i want open a new tab to show file.

The files are in a qnap.

I database i save the record like this... `file://///SERVER2/backups/teste/teste2.txt`

if i copy this link and paste into browser it show me the file but if i put this into anchor tag this doesn't work. Either change page...

```
<a href="file://///SERVER2/backups/teste/teste2.txt" download>
 <div class="download-icon">
  <i class="material-icons">cloud_download</i>
 </div>
</a>
```

What is the problem? How can i solve that?

Thank you

Comment: It will never work this way.

Comment: but if i create a test.html outside of project folder with this anchor tag and link it works well. @BikashPaul

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the file to **public** folder in your laravel project and then you can access the file in a href tag using the `asset` helper function.

`href="{{asset('teste2.txt')}}"`

Comment: but the files are in a folder outside of project folder @SapneshNaik

Comment: the file link which you are using is a static link accssible on only your computer. Have you thought about what happens when you push it to a production server? where the link might not be valid at all

Comment: this is to run in localhost @SapneshNaik

Answer (score 0):

In anchor tag when you put the url then mention http: or https: in starting of every url. & set property target="_blank".

```
<a href="http://url" target="_blank">click</a>
```